# Location of Sqlite databases in OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

Im learning Ruby on Rails 3 and would like to see the db structures created by various Scaffold commands in Sqlite3 in order to understand more the process.

In OSX Snow Leopard, entering:

`which sqlite3`

yields:

"/usr/local/bin/sqlite3"

However cant seem to find the databases! Pointing to that location merely yields the following error message:

> connection failed. file is encrypted or is not a database

To view the dbs im using:

[Navicat for Sqlite](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_sqlite/sqlite_detail_mac.html)

anyone enlighten me where the dbs actually reside? "/usr/local/bin/sqlite3" seems to be an symlink to: /usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.7.10/bin/sqlite3s

Comment: `which` tells you where the binary is, nothing of configuration or data.

Answer (score 12):

SQLite is actually serverless, so the DB files by default reside in your rails directory.

For example:

/db/development.sqlite3

You can check where all your sqlite environment databases are on `config/database.yml`

Comment: I'd add that you should check out 'Base' to crack open the .sqlite3 file and browse / edit it